# how to achieve custom icarousel effect

Tags: ios, iphone, icarousel

i have array of images coming from server and i want to show this in this manner. how can i achieve this using icarousel rotatory effect. as in rotatory effect the other images height is coming lower than the front image. i want all images of same height and width.

```
- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    CoverNewsView *coverView;
    if (!coverView)
    {
        coverView = [UtilitiesHelper loadNibNamed:@"CoverNewsView"
                                          ofClass:[CoverNewsView class]];


//        HeadlineConcrete * headlineConcrete = [self.arrayHeadlineNews objectAtIndex:index];
//        NSLog(@"head=== %@",headlineConcrete.post.subject);
//        
//        coverView.labelTitle.text = headlineConcrete.post.subject;
       // [coverView.imageViewCover setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:headlineConcrete.post.image]];
        [coverView.imageViewCover setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[self.arrayCoverImages objectAtIndex:index]]];
    }
    return coverView;




}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the iCarousel delegate method

```
- (CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel valueForOption:(iCarouselOption)option withDefault:(CGFloat)value;
```

Go through the various options to get the desired look; or have a look at the "Options Demo" iCarousel project.

Answer (score 0):

There are many types of iCarousel available.You can use follow iCarousel type to maintain all image height same.

```
carousel.type = iCarouselTypeCustom;
```